# Download audio and not able to play it with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking, avaudioplayer

I am downloading an audio file from a server with the help of AFNetworking. The file is getting downloaded successfully as I ma able to see it through a progress block.
I am storing it in the Documents directory but then I am not able to play it.
Here is my code:-

```
-(void)downloadAudioFileFromUrl:(NSString *)str_url{

    [SVProgressHUD show];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str_url]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"momentsAudioToast.mp3"];
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {


            [self playSound:path];
        }



    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    }];

    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

        //[progressView setProgress: totalBytesWritten*1.0f / totalBytesExpectedToWrite animated: YES];
        NSLog(@"downloaded %lld of %lld bytes and progress is %f", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite, totalBytesWritten*1.0f /  totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
        if(totalBytesWritten >= totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
        {
            //progressView.hidden = YES;
        }
    }];


    [operation start];


}

- (void)playSound:(NSString *)path {
    [self.player prepareToPlay];
    //UIButton *audioButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    //[audioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sound_preview.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path options: 0 error:nil];

    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:audioData error:nil];
    double duration = [self.player duration];

    NSLog(@"%f", duration);
    NSError * error;

    self.player.delegate = self;
    self.player.numberOfLoops = 0;
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);
    }
    else {
        self.player.delegate = self;
        [self.player play];
    }
}
```

Please help if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**First,** ensure that you are keeping strong reference to `AVAudioPlayer` instance `player` like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

**Second,** most likely, it would be path related issue. Try rebuilding the path while playing.

**Third,**, double check if file physically exists and that it plays when you play it in any audio player.

Comment: I have added this condition in the second method if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) and it is returning true and still the duration is coming 0.000. Also strong reference was already done. Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

In Your case if you declare audio player perfect.

And Also set delegate & if you get NSData from audio file from web service.

Then you need to insert one more line of code and check again.

```
[self.player setVolume: 1.0];
```